# Windows 10 error 0xc00000e9 on boot

Tags: windows-10

When I try to boot Windows 10 I get a black screen and an error `0xc00000e9`.

Then Windows does not start or load.

It is very frustrating situation. How to fix this?

Comment: https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-fix-windows-error-0xc00000e9/

Comment: When do you see this error? What are you doing at the time? Is this the first time you've had this error or has it been going on for some time? Is there any other text shown when you get this error? What operating system are you using? ("Windows" or "Windows Server" doesn't narrow it down) You can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1340504/edit) your question to provide more details.

Comment: read all replies.... https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unexpected-io-error-0xc00000e9/ff4a7cb7-8ea4-4b64-909a-8e2a99d67b80

Answer (score 1):

You can boot from an installation media into WINRE to run startup repair. And then run the following command to fix the boot files:

Bootrec /fixmbr

Bootrec /fixboot

Bootrec /scanos

Bootrec /rebuildbcd

sfc /scannow

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth